# A zero function in infinite field is a zero polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

> $k$ is an infinite field and let $f\in k[x_1,...,x_n]$. Then $f$ is zero polynomial in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ if and only if $f$ is the zero function.

I know how to prove it with only one variable, but $f$ in this question has multiple variables.

My idea is to do induction in the number of variables, but I'm not sure on how to proceed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.